# create a haskell function that returns the definition of a Haskell function that implements the expression

Tags: haskell

if I have the following data type

```
data Exp = Var String | Num Integer | OpExp Op Exp Exp data Op = Plus | Times | Minus
```

I would like to create code that takes a name and an Exp and returns the definition of a haskell function that implements the expression. for simplicity, lets assume it will only contain the variables "x" or "y"

so an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
Lib> compile "foo" $ OpExp Times (Num 10) (OpExp Plus (Var "x") (Var "y"))
```

which would return:
"foo x y = (10 * (x + y))"

and this is what I have defined so far

```
compile :: String -> Exp -> String 
compile name exp = name + " x y = undefined"
```

Comment: What is the question here? or better the problem?

Comment: sorry, I guess the question is how to write compile function such that takes a name and an Exp and returns the definition of a Haskell function that implements the expression.
so it will call compile and return haskell code that runs the arguments

pretty much I want to write the function that outputs haskell code

Answer (score 0):

```
compile :: String -> Exp -> String
compile name exp = name ++ " x y = "  ++(exp2string exp)

exp2string:: Exp -> String
exp2string (Var s) = s
exp2string (Num i) = show i
exp2string (OpExp o e1 e2) ="(" ++ (exp2string e1)  ++ (op2string o) ++(exp2string e2) ++ ")"

op2string:: Op -> String
op2string Plus = " + "
op2string Times = " * "
op2string Minus = " - "
```